# Autosuggest Ajax not linking when there is content behind list

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, ajax

So I have a working ajax/jquery dropdown/list that populates results from the database depending on the users input.

Basically is populates a `<li>` for every resu1lt in the database, and makes it into a link that can then go to that persons profile page.

I have tested the code and it works perfectly on the test page, but as soon as it has other content behind it, the links don't work anymore. How can I fix this?

here is the code:

custom.js:

```
/* JS File */

// Start Ready
$(document).ready(function() {  

// Icon Click Focus
$('div.icon').click(function(){
    $('input#search').focus();
});

// Live Search
// On Search Submit and Get Results
function search() {
    var query_value = $('input#search').val();
    $('b#search-string').html(query_value);
    if(query_value !== ''){
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "search.php",
            data: { query: query_value },
            cache: false,
            success: function(html){
                $("ul#results").html(html);
            }
        });
    }return false;    
}

$("input#search").live("keyup", function(e) {
    // Set Timeout
    clearTimeout($.data(this, 'timer'));

    // Set Search String
    var search_string = $(this).val();

    // Do Search
    if (search_string == '') {
        $("ul#results").fadeOut();
        $('h4#results-text').fadeOut();
    }else{
        $("ul#results").fadeIn();
        $('h4#results-text').fadeIn();
        $(this).data('timer', setTimeout(search, 100));
    };
});

});
```

search.php (the file that searches, not the page that is displayed to the user):

```
/************************************************
Search Functionality
************************************************/

// Define Output HTML Formating
$html = '';
$html .= '<li class="result">';
$html .= '<a target="_blank" href="urlString">';
$html .= '<h3>nameString</h3>';
$html .= '<h4>functionString</h4>';
$html .= '</a>';
$html .= '</li>';

// Get Search
$search_string = preg_replace("/[^A-Za-z0-9]/", " ", $_POST['query']);
$search_string = $tutorial_db->real_escape_string($search_string);

// Check Length More Than One Character
if (strlen($search_string) >= 1 && $search_string !== ' ') {
// Build Query
$query = 'SELECT * FROM users WHERE username LIKE "%'.$search_string.'%" OR name LIKE "%'.$search_string.'%"';

// Do Search
$result = $tutorial_db->query($query);
while($results = $result->fetch_array()) {
    $result_array[] = $results;
}

// Check If We Have Results
if (isset($result_array)) {
    foreach ($result_array as $result) {

        // Format Output Strings And Hightlight Matches
        $display_function = preg_replace("/".$search_string."/i", "<b class='highlight'>".$search_string."</b>", $result['function']);
        $display_name = preg_replace("/".$search_string."/i", "<b class='highlight'>".$search_string."</b>", $result['name'] . " " . $result['surname'] . " (" . $result['username'] . ")");
        $display_url = 'timeline.php?user='.$result['username'];

        // Insert Name
        $output = str_replace('nameString', $display_name, $html);

        // Insert Function
        $output = str_replace('functionString', $display_function,     $output);

        // Insert URL
        $output = str_replace('urlString', $display_url, $output);

        // Output
        echo($output);
    }
}else{

    // Format No Results Output
    $output = str_replace('urlString', 'javascript:void(0);', $html);
    $output = str_replace('nameString', '<b>No Results Found.</b>', $output);
    $output = str_replace('functionString', 'Sorry :(', $output);

    // Output
    echo($output);
}
}
```

And the search form itself:

```
<!-- Main Input -->
<input type="text" id="search" autocomplete="off">

<!-- Show Results -->
<h4 id="results-text">Showing results for: <b id="search-string">Array</b></h4>
<ul id="results"></ul>
```

All this code can be found here: [live search with ajax, php and mysql](http://blog.ninetofive.me/blog/build-a-live-search-with-ajax-php-and-mysql/)
credits to him.

thanks for the help in advance!

Comment: "as soon as it has other content behind it, the links don't work anymore", Is this a positioning or a functionality issue when other content is added to the structure of the page?

Comment: The list drops down from the header and over the main content, and then the links don't want to work.

Comment: Have you tried giving the container with all the ajax content a z-index: 99999999?

Comment: Yes I have, and it still does nothing

Comment: Are you getting any console errors?

Comment: can you provide a link to example in which you are using content in background and links are not working?

Comment: The only other answers I can offer would be to set the positioning to absolute or fixed and see if that fixes things.

Comment: I set the positioning to absolute and the z-index to 99 and it worked! thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I got it working thanks to Enijar.

Set the positioning to absolute and the z-index to 99.